# How to pan openseadragon mutli image viewer within the bounds

Tags: html, css, image, openseadragon

I have a multi image openseadragon viewer, where the coordinates of each tiled image seem to be calculated based on the size of the image to the container viewer size. When the user clicks on a specific image I am trying to fit the image to the center of the viewport by using fitBounds method. Here I am passing the bound rect of the image the user has clicked. This is working perfectly. Now I have a requirement where say a panel is placed on the right side, on top of the viewer, I need to consider the boundary till the left of the panel(Viewer area includes the area under the right side panel). What this means is that, though the viwer need to occupy full width, the image that need to be fit should concider only the center between the left of the viewer upto left of the panel(excludes the area under the panel). I tried doing PanTo but couldn't understand how to calculate the center for a multi image scenario.It doesn't seem to be accurate. The x coordinate of the 4th image seem to be at 4.9 and am trying to see how I can calculate a correct coordinate center for each image where I can panTo.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I highly recommend sticking with fitBounds... if you want the viewer in a different location than the literal bound rect of the image, adjust that rectangle before calling fitBounds. I might be able to give a more detailed recommendation if you provide an image illustrating what you're trying to do, or a codepen or something.